# Unsupported Culture in .NET application under Wine

Tags: wine

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Dotnet20 has been installed using winetricks.
When I attempt to run a .net application, the application throws a System.ArgumentException, stating the error message:

> System.ArgumentException: Culture name 'ga-ie' is not supported.

The application has no reason to load `ga-ie` as far as I know; Ubuntu is running in American English locale, but I'm not sure how to check this as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an answer to your question, but have you looked at the [mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) ?
I've decided to not run programs through Wine, so I can't really help you there. You could try look for locale settings in Wine, though.
Myself, I run a virtual machine in Ubuntu with windows installed, through VMplayer. No wine needed.

Sorry if I went really off-topic with regards to your question.